# S3 - copying public files to local s3 gives access denied error

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, minio

When I run this command:

```
mc cp --recursive s3-ghaf/bucket s3-local/bucket
```

I get this error:

```
mc: <ERROR> Failed to copy `https://url/bucket/admin/css/base.css`. Access Denied.
mc: <ERROR> Failed to copy `https://url/bucket/admin/css/fonts.css`. Access Denied.
```

But when I open the files `https://url/bucket/admin/css/fonts.css` etc in my browser they open just fine.

s3-local is the minio I have on my own laptop.

The bucket policy is public.

Any thoughts on why I'm getting access denied error?

I don't know if it matters but I'm running minio in a k8s cluster.

Comment: it could be that the path has invalid characters as per object naming restrictions in S3.  Please update and mark as answered if it is resolved.